# Convert BSON to JSON and send as API response Haskell

Tags: json, mongodb, haskell, bson, scotty

I'm working on my first Haskell web app, and am having trouble converting a BSON document into JSON and then sending it as an API response. I'm currently using the `AesonBson` package to convert my BSON to an Aeson `Object`, but can't figure out how to send that Aeson `Object` as a JSON API response.

Here is an example of a route handler in my server:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Web.Routes where


import Web.Scotty
import Web.Utils
import Web.Actions.Database
import Control.Monad.Trans (liftIO)
import Data.AesonBson


routes :: ScottyM ()
routes = do
  get "/databases/:db/:collection" $ do
      db <- param "db"
      collection <- param "collection"
      docs <- liftIO $ getAllDocuments "127.0.0.1" db collection
      json $ map aesonify docs
```

These seems like it should be simple - `getAllDocuments` returns `IO [Document]`, and then I map `aesonfy` over my list of docs, before attempting to return them as a JSON server response.

Problem is I keep getting this `No instance for ToJSON` error:

```
No instance for (aeson-0.8.0.2:Data.Aeson.Types.Class.ToJSON
                   aeson-0.6.2.1:Data.Aeson.Types.Internal.Value)
  arising from a use of ‘Web.Scotty.json’
In the expression: Web.Scotty.json
In a stmt of a 'do' block:
  Web.Scotty.json
  GHC.Base.$ GHC.Base.map Data.AesonBson.aesonify docs
In the second argument of ‘(GHC.Base.$)’, namely
  ‘do { db <- Web.Scotty.param "db";
        collection <- Web.Scotty.param "collection";
        docs <- transformers-0.3.0.0:Control.Monad.IO.Class.liftIO
                GHC.Base.$
                  Web.Actions.Database.getAllDocuments "127.0.0.1" db collection;
        Web.Scotty.json
        GHC.Base.$ GHC.Base.map Data.AesonBson.aesonify docs }’
```

Any idea what I am missing? It looks like `aesonify` returns an Aeson `Object`... shouldn't that be an instace of `ToJSON`? Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been spinning my wheels on this one for a while now. I've tried placing Aeson's `object` function in different places, manually adding documents as an instance of `ToJSON`, but really can't figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

You have two different versions of `aeson` package: `aeson-0.8.0.2` and `aeson-0.6.2.1`. Clearly the `Value` from `aeson-0.6.2.1` is not an instance of `FromJSON` from `aeson-0.8.0.2`.

I'd recommend you to cabalize the code and/or use cabal sandbox. Alternatively you can use `ghc-pkg` to unregister one of `aeson` versions.

ADD: you seems to have the same issue with `transformers-0.3.0.0`. GHC never qualifies identifiers with package name and version in error messages unless it is ambiguous. Try `ghc-pkg list transformers`

Comment: Oh damn, haha, can't believe I missed that (or, well to be fair I'm still pretty bad at reading Haskell error messages, so maybe 'missed' isn't the right term). Thank you a ton for taking a look at that.

I do use cabal for managing my dependencies, but probably got myself into a bad spot with reckless package install sessions.

Comment: So simply removing `aeson 0.8` fixed the problem (`AesonBson` seems to rely on `aeson 0.6`, thanks again for the help on that one. I tried running `ghc-pkg list transformers` and got two results, but I'm not really sure what it's telling me. Do you see a problem? 

`/usr/local/Cellar/ghc/7.8.4/lib/ghc-7.8.4/package.conf.d
   transformers-0.3.0.0
/Users/tolson/.ghc/x86_64-darwin-7.8.4/package.conf.d`